# Two Independent Delegate Methods in a Class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have two independent delegate methods in a class.

```
    - (void)delegateMethod1:(id)data {
         self.data = data;
    }

    - (void)delegateMethod2 {
         [someClass sendData:self.data];
    }
```

Now, this works fine sometimes but the other times, delegateMethod2 gets called before delegateMethod1.

I need to know how to manage this elegantly so that the line: `[someClass sendData:self.data];` gets called only when both delegateMethod1 and delegateMethod2 have been called.

I know I can do it by using a variable to set to something on each delegate call but there has to be an elegant way to do this.

Any help?

Comment: How are the delegate methods called?

Comment: They are independently called on different events. The important thing is that both are called within a very short span of time.

Comment: You question seems to be a bit confusing. You have placed the [someClass sendData:] method within the delegateMethod2 and after that you say that [someClass sendData:] should only be called after both delegateMethod1 and delegateMethod2 have been called. How can this happen ? If delegateMethod2 is called then it will directly cal the [someClass sendData:] method. Kindly elaborate on this.

Comment: ^ You are right, it's a little confusing. 
In my example, I did the [someClass sendData:] in the delegateMethod2 because that's the way it is in the current implementation as usually delegateMethod2 is called after delegateMethod1 but not for certain. I don't mind calling [someClass sendData:] somewhere other than delegateMethod2.

Comment: @NSFeaster: So `[someClass sendData:self.data]` should be called after *both* delegate methods have been called?

Comment: Exactly..you are right.

Comment: @NSFeaster do you use `respondToSelector` method for invoke every delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembering which delegate has been called seems the easiest and cleanest solution to me.
But you can make it *symmetric* by moving the check to a separate method, so that
is does not matter which delegate is called first:

```
- (void)checkIfDataCanBeSent {
    if (self.method1called && self.method2called) {
         [someClass sendData:self.data];
    }
}

- (void)delegateMethod1:(id)data {
     self.method1called = YES;
     // ...
     [self checkIfDataCanBeSent];
}

- (void)delegateMethod2 {
     self.method2called = YES;
     // ...
     [self checkIfDataCanBeSent];
}
```

(I have assumed that all delegate methods are called on the main thread, otherwise
one would have to add some synchronization.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, using a indicative variable to be the most elegant way to get over this. But this variable has to be kept in the delegate caller object.

Pseudo-type explanation

```
@interface DelegateCaller
{
   BOOL hasCalled1stMethod;
}
@property(nonatomic,weak) id delegate;
@end

@implementation DelegateCaller

-(void)in_some_process_1
{
   [self.delegate delegateMethod1]; //call
   hasCalled1stMethod = YES; //set indicator
}

-(void)in_some_process_2
{
   if(hasCalled1stMethod)
    {
       [self.delegate delegateMethod2]; //call
       hasCalled1stMethod = NO; //reset indicator for reuse, if required.
     }
}

@end
```

This way you'll not have to maintain any variable in the delegate itself, because the regulation of calling is maintained in the caller-object itself.

Another case: 
If the delegateMethod1 is called from some object1 and the delegateMethod2 is called from some other object2, then again the indicative variable method is the most elegant way (in this limited scenario)

Pseudo-type explanation:

```
@interface ClassDelegateObject //aka the callee
{
  BOOL hasCalledMethod1;
}
@end

@implementation ClassDelegateObject

-(void)delegateMethod1:(NSData*)data
{
   self.data = data; 
   hasCalledMethod1 = YES; //set the indicator.
}

-(void)delegateMethod2
{
   //here relying on the self.data!=nil will not be fruitful
   //in case the self.data is not nil and hold some previous garbage data then
   //this logic will fail.

   if(hasCalledMethod1) 
   {
     [someClass sendData:self.data]; 
     hasCalledMethod1 = NO; //reset the variable for reuse if required.
   }
}

@end
```

Comment: You are assuming that both the delegates are being called from the same class which is not true.

Comment: Ok, please edit and add this piece of information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you rethink how the code works. Maybe you can check if there is no data and if so send it once it is ready:

```
- (void)delegateMethod1:(id)data {
     self.data = data;
     if (self.dataShouldBeSentWhenReady) {
       [self sendData];
     }
}

- (void)delegateMethod2 {
     if (self.data) {
       [self sendData];
     } else {
       [self setDataShouldBeSentWhenReady:YES];
     }
}

- (void)sendData {
    [self setDataShouldBeSentWhenReady:NO];
    [someClass sendData:self.data];
}
```